# How to get notification about window opened or created in e4

Tags: eclipse, e4

In AddOn we can get notification about application start completed by following method:

```
    @Optional
    @Inject
    public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE)
                           org.osgi.service.event.Event event)
```

Can we get notification about aplication window was opened? I try to listen   `UIEvents.TrimmedWindow.TOPIC_ALL`   and  `UIEvents.Window.TOPIC_ALL`  but nothing happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an addon is created the main application window has already been created so you can just find that using `EModelService`.

The `UIEvents.UIElement.TOPIC_TOBERENDERED` event will tell you about all UI objects when they are rendered by calling `MUIElement.setToBeRendered` (made visible or hidden):

```java
@Inject
@Optional
void event(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UIElement.TOPIC_TOBERENDERED) Event event)
{
  if (event == null)
    return;

  // The UI element
  Object element = event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.ELEMENT);

  // Rendered or hidden value
  Boolean toBeRendered = (Boolean)event.getProperty(UIEvents.EventTags.NEW_VALUE);
```

However this event isn't generated for objects generated dynamically which don't call `setToBeRendered`

The `UIEvents.Context.TOPIC_CONTEXT` event is fired for creation of all objects in which a context is set - biut it may be fired at other times as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But method `void event(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UIElement.TOPIC_TOBERENDERED) Event event)` never calls.

Comment: I use exactly this call to track part closures. It does also fire for some opens, but not all, it depends how they are done. Make sure that `Event` is `org.osgi.service.event.Event` using any of the other `Event` classes will stop it working.

Comment: Something that does fire for all creations is `UIEvents.Context.TOPIC_CONTEXT` but it may also be fired at other times as well.